# Many Testcase classes inside a test.py in django don't run correctly

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I want to have different Testcase classes inside my test.py in my django project. One for Model testing (crud) one for view testing etc. I have the following classes

```
class EntryModelTest(TestCase):
    LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @classmethod
    def setup_database(cls):
       #database initialization


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(EntryModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.setup_database()
        cls.myModel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
        #some queries (additions) that use things that were added in setup_database()
```

and a second testcase

```
class MyCalViewsTest(TestCase):
    LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @classmethod
    def setup_database(cls):
        #exactly the same code as above testcase(I know I could use Inheretiance. Will refactor)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #The same as above testcase
        cls.myModel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1) #this gives the following error: DoesNotExist: PracticeData matching query does not exist.
```

The MyModel instance is created in setup_database method. I am not quite sure why. If the test database is destroyed after every testcase class is executed then the setup_database method should have recreated the MyModel instance with pk=1 so I would have existed. If it doesn't destroy the test database then the MyModel instance with pk=1 already exists so I shouldn't have any problems also. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very unclear. What does the setup_database method do? Django's TestCase class already creates the database and takes care of truncating it after every test. Why would you expect the pk autoincrement sequence to be reset?

Comment: setup_database creates some model instances nothing more. I would expect th pk autoincrement sequence to be reset if the test database is destroyed after every test class.If not then the MyModel  object with pk=1 should already exist in my test database thus it shouldn't give me the error.

Comment: But, your tests are showing that is not the case, and nothing in the documentation claims it does happen. The database is emptied, not destroyed.

Comment: Why don't you use [model_mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy)? ```mommy.make(MyModel, my_controlled_attribute='value')```.

Comment: @DanielRoseman tests work when run individually, but not when run alltogether. Documentation states that database is destroyed when all tests have finished(https://goo.gl/wYfKyx). And I ask if you know what is a test. The test method inside a Testcase Class? The testcase class?